# What does "Function call stack: train_function" mean in image recognition AI?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So I am trying use a image recognition AI for a project. The module I using is the one on this website https://towardsdatascience.com/train-image-recognition-ai-with-5-lines-of-code-8ed0bdd8d9ba. I have installed all the pips and to their given variations.

```
from imageai.Classification.Custom import ClassificationModelTrainer

directory = "C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\AI Project\\idenprof-jpg\\idenprof\\"
model_trainer = ClassificationModelTrainer()
model_trainer.setModelTypeAsResNet50()
model_trainer.setDataDirectory(directory)
model_trainer.trainModel(num_objects=10, num_experiments=200, enhance_data=True, batch_size=32, show_network_summary=True)
```

and then I get this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\AI Project\Test 2.py", line 7, in 
> model_trainer.trainModel(num_objects=10, num_experiments=200, enhance_data=True, batch_size=32, show_network_summary=True)
> File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\imageai\Classification\Custom_*init*_.py", line 393, in trainModel
> model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=int(num_train / batch_size), epochs=self.__num_epochs,
> File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1847, in fit_generator
> return self.fit(
> File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1100, in fit
> tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
> File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 828, in **call**
> result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
> File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 888, in _call
> return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
> File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2942, in **call**
> return graph_function._call_flat(
> File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1918, in _call_flat
> return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
> File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 555, in call
> outputs = execute.execute(
> File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 59, in quick_execute
> tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx.*handle, device_name, op_name,
> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[32,10] labels_size=[32,13]
> [[node categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits (defined at C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\imageai\Classification\Custom_*init**.py:393) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_11908]
> Function call stack:
> train_function

What can I do to resolve this? Also, sorry if the formatting is incorrect it is the first time asking a question.

Comment: you want to know what `train_function` is, or do you want to solve this problem? because then we can't solve your problem without seeing the code, and the title isn't representative of what you actually want to know. i can explain what `train_function` is but it won't help solving your issue in any way

Answer (score 1):

`train_function` is a function hidden under the hood when you call `model.fit()`. It looks roughly like this:

```
def train_step(self, data):
    x, y = data

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)  # Forward pass
        # Compute our own loss
        loss = keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y, y_pred)

    # Compute gradients
    trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)

    # Update weights
    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))

    # Compute our own metrics
    loss_tracker.update_state(loss)
    mae_metric.update_state(y, y_pred)
    return {"loss": loss_tracker.result(), "mae": mae_metric.result()}
```

When you see this in your traceback, it only indicates that the error is somewhere within this function. As you can see, it can be many things, as there are many operations in `train_function`. But, if you look up, there is more information. In your case:

> InvalidArgumentError: logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[32,10] labels_size=[32,13] [[node categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits

Your neural network has 10 output neurons, but your labels have 13 categories.